# More succinct way to write a pandas moving average for several columns

Tags: python, pandas, join

I have a df with four columns as below:

| A | B | C | D |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | 55 | 45 | 23 |
| 3 | 78 | 78 | 20 |

...

I would like to take a moving average of all of the columns with new names, and keep the original columns too. I can do this using:

```
cols=['A','B','C','D']

df[cols].rolling(window=28, min_periods=14).mean().join(df, rsuffix='x').rename(columns={'A':'28d_A','B':'28d_B','C':'28d_C','D':'28d_D'})
```

Is there a better way which doesn't require me to rename all the columns and do a join? Thanks

Comment: IIUC, directly assigning with `df["28_d" + pd.Index(cols)] = df[cols].rolling(...).mean()` where `pd.Index` is used for easier string addition to column names.

Comment: @MustafaAydın nice that worked very well. What is pd.Index actually doing here?

Comment: `pd.Index` is used for easier string addition to column names. It supports directly adding `"28_d"`. Otherwise, with Python lists, you'd need to loop explicitly e.g. `df[["28_d" + col_name for col_name in cols]] = ...`.

Answer (score 0):

You can us a **dict** comprehension to `assign()`. Sample data is too short for output to be meaningful.

```
cols=['A','B','C','D']
df.assign(**{f"28d_{c}":df[c].rolling(window=28, min_periods=14).mean() for c in cols})
``
```